# Control slot car with Arduino

Tags: arduino, breadboard, prototyping

I'm brand new at electronics, and brand new at Arduino. I know very little about eighter, so please bear over with me... :-) To top it of, this is my very first post here on Electronics.

I'm working as a frontend developer, and my first Arduino project is about controlling a slot car via a website.

I can turn an LED on and off, remotely from a website, and I have connected the slot car to the Arduino, like I connected the LED, but of course there isn't enough power to get it running very fast. I does run, but sloooow... :-) I used a digital multi meter and saw that there were only 2V in the tracks, compared to 14.8V when plugged in the wall.

With my very limited knowledge of electronics, I was wondering if I could plug the slot car into the normal power socket, and somehow control how much power that goes into the tracks with Arduino.

How do I do that? With a resistor? Or?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/arduino-speed-controllers-for-rc-cars?rq=1

Comment: Also, this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32047/arduino-controlled-slot-cars-alternative-to-mosfets-for-speed-control?rq=1 ended up using https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9670

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your powering the slot car directly from the arduino. Bad idea. Slot cars use a 120vac xformer to step down to 18vdc (Approx. dont really know the exact, look on your controller to see). By "normal power socket" I assume you mean 120vac wall power. Keep everything hooked up like it normally would (the slot car setup), then I would use the arduino to control a digital pot interfaced with the slot car throttle. You could have a slider control on the web site thats interfaced w/ the arduino dig. pot to control the speed. There are many other ways, but you being new to this, would be more complicated. Good luck.